# A question on TCP connection buffers

Tags: c, networking, tcp

Linux.

I have an ethernet cable between two computers. A simple server-client program in C to transfer a file from client to server. Client reads 100 bytes of data from the file and sends it to the server, and then waits for 2 seconds before sending the next packet.

When the client was sending the data, I pulled out the ethernet cable of the server side, I was expecting some error from the client since the connection is broke. But the client kept on writing the data to the pipe, and the server did not receive anything(but still it is waiting to receive).Client sent the whole file and stopped. Now, again I connect the ethernet cable, the server receives all the data sent by the client. How is this possible? Are the packets stored in some buffer and sent again when the connection is up?

Sorry for making it too long.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The whole point of TCP is to provide reliable data transfer *despite* having an unreliable network underneath. Basically, the way it works is TCP only considers data sent after it receives an acknowledgement packet from the remote machine; until then, the kernel stores the data locally. The amount of time it'll be buffered for can be quite long, depending on a bunch of settings in `/proc` as well as measured network parameters.

edit: An app can check the size of the outstanding send queue by using the `SIOCOUTQ` ioctl; see the tcp(7) manpage. The same manpage discusses error handling as well.

If you want that data to be lost instead of buffered, use UDP.

Comment: Exactly. That is my understanding too. I don't want the data to be lost. I want a reliable connection. Now it stores in kernel and since the client program doesn't get any errors, he happily sends the whole file and exits. Now lets say, the connection is not going to be recovered, and TCP will release the kernel buffers and the client doesnt know this. How is reliability maintained here?

Comment: @Blacklabel: Your app will see the connection reset, so the client can know. If the connection is reset, there isn't any guarantee data was delivered. Unfortunately, all abstractions leak; this one is called the "Two Generals' Problem"

Comment: @Blacklabel: You should also consider that even if the remote machine has received and acknowledged the data, it then sits in the remote machine's TCP receive buffer until the app requests it. If the remote app crashes, or otherwise fails to handle the data...

Comment: @Derobert. Thanks a lot. I understood :). Another amateur question, how can I find if a connection is reset in C?

Comment: And also it is possible to disable this feature. So that my send fails if the connection is broke?

Comment: @Blacklabel: You don't *want* to disable this feature.  What you do want is to have your sending application wait until the recieving *application* has notified it that the data has been recieved and saved to disk (or otherwise dealt with).  "Correctly recieved" is an application-level property, it can't be dealt with at the TCP layer.

Comment: @Blacklabel: If you need to know if the other end got the data, have the other end send you something to indicate that it got the data. You are the one designing the data to be sent in each direction.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Depending on the configuration, it even may wait some time to see if it can recover the connection. Even, tcp timeouts can be of minutes... Note [here](http://linux.die.net/man/7/tcp) for example, the parameter `tcp_fin_timeout` and other parameters related to timeouts.

Comment: thanks for your time. that link is useful. But I am missing something here. Reliability is lost here. If TCP buffers it, and later if the connection is not recovered it is ultimately going to drop the packets. Now the client doesn't know about this and it thinks that it sent the packets.

Comment: Not exactly. If the packets cannot be sent (timeout), an error will be sent to the client (closed connection). If they can be sent, they will, even if you disconnect, then connects, so no error. Package lost always implies an error returned to the client.

Comment: No it doesn't: the client may have already closed the socket, so there is no way to deliver the error in that case. In general you can't know that the final transmission has arrived. This is known as the two-army problem.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, you can see the kernel-maintained send-queue and timeouts by running:

```
netstat -tanpo
```

When the connections terminates abruptly, due to an error or a timeout, the client can notice by checking the return values from `write()`, `shutdown()` and `close()`.